# Changing substring in a String

Tags: regex, vbscript, automation

I've got a variable "Variable" in VBScript that will receive different values, based on names that come from xml files i don't trust. I can't let "Variable" have forbidden caracters on it (<, >, :, ", /, \, |, ?, * ) or characters with accents (I think they are called accent in english) like (Á, á, É, é, Â, â, Ê, ê, ñ, ã).

So, my question is: How can I create a script that studies and replace these possible multiple possible characters in the variable I have? I'm using a Replace function found in MSDN Library, but it won't let me alter many characters in the way I'm using it.

Example:

(Assuming a Node.Text value of "Example A/S")

```
For Each Node In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//NameUsedToRenameFile")
     Variable = Node.Text
Next

Result = Replace(Variable, "<", "-")
Result = Replace(Variable, "/", "-")
```

WScript.Echo Result
This Echo above returns me "Example A-S", but if I change my Replaces order, like:

```
Result = Replace(Variable, "/", "-")
Result = Replace(Variable, "<", "-")
```

I get a "Example A/S". How should I program it to be prepared to any possible characters? Thanks!

Comment: You should define a list of allowed characters. This makes it easier to put things under control.

Comment: You'd have to create some sort of mapping array/object I believe.

Comment: And String is immutable, so you need to pass the Result to the next Replace, not Variable.

Comment: Why it functions in the first example, but not in the second?

Comment: @CharlieVelez: Like I said, you need to pass Result to the next Replace. Otherwise, the result you see is only the Variable being replace once, by the last line of replacement.

Comment: @nhahtdh, I want only the alpha numeric ones, without accents.

Comment: You will run into problems doing this. Vbscript will not understand certain Unicode characters. Better to create a list of allowed characters instead as suggested earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, it might be easier to do things the other way around; create a list of allowed characrters as VBScript is not so good at handling unicode like characters; whilst the characters you have listed may be fine, you may run into issues with certain character sets. here's an example routine that could help your cause:

Consider this command:

```
wscript.echo ValidateStr("This393~~_+'852Is0909A========Test|!:~@$%#@@#")
```

Using the sample routine below, it should produce the following results:

> This393852Is0909ATest

The sample routine:

```
Function ValidateStr (vsVar)
    Dim vsAllowed, vscan, vsaScan, vsaCount
    vsAllowed = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
    ValidateStr = ""
    If vartype(vsvar) = vbString then
        If len(vsvar) > 0 then 
            For vscan = 1 To Len(vsvar)
               vsValid = False          
               vsaCount = 1
               Do While vsaValid = false and vsaCount <= len(vsAllowed)
                   If UCase(Mid(vsVar, vscan, 1)) = Mid(vsAllowed, vsaCount, 1) Then vsValid = True
                   vsaCount = vsaCount + 1
               Loop
               If vsValid Then ValidateStr = ValidateStr & Mid(vsVar, vscan,1)
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

I hope this helps you with your quest. Enjoy!

EDIT: If you wish to continue with your original path, you will need to fix your replace command - it is not working because you are resetting it after each line. You'll need to pump in `variable` the first time, then use `result` every subsequent time..

You had:

```
Result = Replace(Variable, "/", "-")
Result = Replace(Variable, "<", "-")
```

You need to change this to:

```
Result = Replace(Variable, "/", "-")
Result = Replace(Result, "<", "-")
Result = Replace(Result, ...etc..)
Result = Replace(Result, ...etc..)
```

Edit: You could try Ansgar's Regex, as the code is by far more simple, but I am not sure it will work if as an example you had simplified Chinese characters in your string.

Comment: It functioned perfectly. Thanks a lot, mate!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Damien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21165513/1630171) that replacing everything but known-good characters is the better approach. I would, however, use a regular expression for this, because it greatly simplifies the code. I would also recommend to not remove "bad" characters, but to replace them with a known-good placeholder (an underscore for instance), because removing characters might yield undesired results.

```
Function SanitizeString(str)
  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
  re.Global  = True

  SanitizeString = re.Replace(str, "_")
End Function
```

Comment: Hello again, @Ansgar! I'll try it too!